# jQuery Cycle onAfter triggering too quickly

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I'm using the [jQuery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) plugin with an `onAfter()` event that supposedly fires when a transition has finished. The function checks for an element with opacity:1, and copies its first child div into another element...

```
function onAfter(){
    var theslide = $('#slides > div').filter(function() {
        return $(this).css('opacity') == '1';
    });
    $(theslide.children('div')).clone().appendTo('#content', function(){
        $('#content').fadeIn(800);
    });
};
```

It almost works - it triggers fine when the page loads, but seems to run too quickly on subsequent transitions, meaning that no element actually has opacity:1 and nothing is copied.

If I delay the important part of the function slightly (with, for example, an alert) like so...

```
function onAfter(){
    alert(something);
    var theslide = $('#slides > div').filter(function() {
        return $(this).css('opacity') == '1';
    });
    ...
};
```

...this seems to give it enough time to find a div with full opacity.

My question is, how can I properly and reliably ensure that there is a fully opaque div for the code to find?

Comment: why can't you just get the current slide from arguments of the `after` callback?

Comment: A good question - I'm looking at that alternative now. I'd still be interested to know how to achieve the original question though, for reference's sake.

Comment: go for the absolute from arguments, it's already defined . requires no search of DOM, and as witnessed your approach isn't working